# Boost github release does not contain submodules

Tags: c++, git, github, boost

I was trying to download the boost release from https://github.com/boostorg/boost/releases and on downloading the release I saw that the submodules that it uses have not been initialized.  Is this intentional?

Since all the relevant code for boost has beeb modularized into git submodules and they are each maintained in their own git repo.  How then can I get the submodules off the github release (or initialize the submodules into the downloaded code)?  [Apparently the github `git archive` API does not support submodules for security reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34719785/how-to-add-submodule-files-to-a-github-release).

Comment: Alternate solution - get the archive from [boost.org](http://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_63_0.html), and if you want the source off github, use `git clone --recursive`

Comment: @Praetorian I knew about the boost.org release link, I was just curious why the github page had releases when they didn't contain all the code for the submodules :(

Comment: so what do you expect as an answer to this question?

Comment: @eis the question I wanted to ask was how one is supposed to get the submodules from the github release of boost.  I don't know if I was doing something wrong

Comment: @Curious but you do know? You yourself linked to thread explaining that github releases do not support them, and Praetorian commented on the alternate solution. So is there anything left to answer?

Comment: The automatic archive which is provided by github is nor a real released archive, it's just automatic snapshot. For a typical source project it could also miss something like `./configure` script which usually not included in VCS but generated. The right way for them would be to attach their archives to the release in github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you commented, github releases do not support submodules.

Sources:

- https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-c/issues/6
- https://github.com/adobe/brackets/issues/9068
- [Include a GitHub submodule automatically in download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12936014/include-a-github-submodule-automatically-in-download)

Like @Praetorian mentioned, alternate solution is to get the archive [from boost](http://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_63_0.html), or just clone the source with submodules from github. You can [clone off a tag or a branch to get specific version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11030332/365237) with `git clone --branch my_abc http://git.abc.net/git/abc.git`, and use `--recursive` to get submodules.

Comment: Would you happen to know why boost does not want their releases to contain all the submodules?  Or is that not something that they want to do entirely?

Comment: @Curious why do you say boost doesn't want? It's a limitation of github releases, not of boost.