# GitHub zip download with empty submodule folder

Tags: git, github, git-submodules

I have a repo on GitHub with a submodule. The submodule directory is contained

- in the root directory of the repo directly on github.com
- and also in the zip that can be downloaded from github.com.

If I click on the directory on github.com, there is the expected content (of the submodule). However, in the zip, the submodule directory is empty.

How can I fix this?

It is important that people who download the root module, automatically get all the submodule content in order to be able to use it. Thank you!

Comment: A submodule is a separate Git repository. It requires two `git clone` steps to get both the superproject and the submodule. Using `git clone --recursive` tells the superproject `git clone` step to run the submodule `git clone` step, but that's something the person *running* `git clone` must *request*. You can't do that for them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I [mentioned before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34721233/6309), a submodule is *not* included in a [GitHub archive (tarball/zipfile)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8378458/6309).

You need to add to your [GitHub release](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/releasing-projects-on-github/managing-releases-in-a-repository) an artifact representing the full cloned repository (like [`git-archive-all.sh`](https://github.com/fabacab/git-archive-all.sh/blob/master/git-archive-all.sh)).

Comment: Thank you. I am not really familiar with the bash syntax. But probably, I can also create such an archive by hand and mention in the readme that people should download the release and not the GitHub archive.

Comment: @Kolodez Note: you can execute a bash script even on Windows, using the bash packaged with Git for Windows.